# SQL - Subtract Date with Integer

Tags: sql, date, datetime, subtraction

I have a document that has "Delivery Date" and "Days to Deliver" fields
I would like to calculate a "Dispatch Date" = "Delivery Date" subtract "Days to Deliver".

Currently I'm trying:

```
dbo.t0.docduedate-dbo.crd1.daystodeliver`
```

I am getting a datetime format error for above.  Where am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the DateAdd() function? You can use negative numbers

Comment: DateAdd is not available on all rdbms's.  That vital piece of information has not been provided by endless12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using SQL server, you could use SQL [function `DATEADD()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186819.aspx).
First parameter is `d` which stands for day.
 Second parameter is how many days you want to add and putting minus `(-)` in front instead of adding subtracts the value.
Last parameter is initial date itself that you want to be manipulated.
You might need to cast input values to appropriate types - second parameter has to be integer.

```
SELECT DATEADD(d,-[DaysToDeliver], [DeliveryDate]) AS 'Dispatch Date' FROM [TABLE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select Dispatchdate = Dateadd(dd,-daystodeliver,Deliverydate)
from table
```